# Check if values exits in database

Tags: android

I want to check if a couple of values exists in the database. If they do, the method should return TRUE or FALSE if the cursor is null. But the problem is that it returns TRUE all the time despite the values are not in the database! What have I missed?

```
    // This method check if the combination image path and contact name already exists in database
public boolean checkContentDatabase(String imageFilePath, String contactName) {

    String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE+ " where " + TABLE_IMAGE_PATH + "='" + imageFilePath + "' and " + TABLE_CONTACT_NAME + "='" + contactName +"' ;";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(c != null) // Exists in database
     {
     return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your if condition with:

```
if(c.getCount() > 0)
 {
 return true;
 }
 else
 {
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

use `c != null && c.getCount() > 0` instead of `c != null`

Answer (score 2):

```
      public boolean checkContentDatabase(String imageFilePath, String contactName) {

String query = "Select * from " + DB_TABLE+ " where " + TABLE_IMAGE_PATH      + "='"          +          imageFilePath + "' and " + TABLE_CONTACT_NAME + "='" + contactName +"' ;";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);


           c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.isAfterLast() == false) {
       return true;
      }
     else
       {
      return false;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is not null, because its been created successfully. Only your result set does not exist. Try using "SELECT 1 FROM..." and then check if the result equals 1.

Comment: Or "SELECT COUNT(*)", so the DBMS does even bigger part of the work.

Comment: With Count(*) the DBMS has actual something to do. When the table has many rows and the WHERE-Clause is'nt very restrictive, the DBMS needs alot of time to count something, which is not interesting at all, because you only want to know, if something exists and not how many of them.

Comment: Sadly, you're right. If only there was `IS EMPTY` or something like this... but that would require SQL to have Boolean values.